# JavaScript Get Window Plus Scroll Size

Tags: javascript, overlay

I created a JavaScript overlay function with a re-size listener.  Everything works except when  there's a scroll.  Lets say the screen is 1024x768 but the website's content takes up 1500x700, so there's only a vertical scroll.  Which JavaScript function can detect the amount of scroll so it can be covered by the overlay?  Because right now JavaScript detects 1024x768 and when I scroll, the overlay stops.  (If the body background is white and over overlay is black, it'll display black for 1024 but for the remaining 476px, white is displayed.) Below is my code, I've cut it down to the relevant sections.  After that has been solved, any tips for IE support would be appreciated.  So far it doesn't render correctly in IE 8.

```
//Index.html
renderOverlay("image.jpg");


//Overlay.js
renderOverlay(img){
  if(resizeListener){ //global variable
    var overlay = document.createElement("div");
    overlay.className = "overlay"; //Contains overlay background color, positioning etc
    overlay.id = "overlay";
    overlay.style.width = getWindowSize("width");
    overlay.style.height = getWindowSize("height");
    overlay.innerHTML = "<img src='"+file+"' />";

    document.appendChild(overlayWrapper);
    window.addEventListener("resize", function(){renderOverlay(img)}, false);
  }else{
    document.getElementById("overlay").style.width = getWindowSize("width");
    document.getElementById("overlay").style.height = getWindowSize("height");
  }
}


//getWindowSize.js
getWindowSize(dimension){
  if(typeof(window.innerWidth) == "number"){
    if(dimension == "width"){
      return(window.innerWidth+"px");
    }else{
      return(window.innerHeight+"px");
    }
  }
}

//CSS
.overlay{
background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
left: 0;
overflow: auto;
position: fixed;
text-align: center;
top: 0;
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use CSS to fix the position of the overlay:

```
#overlay {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}
```

Comment: Works great.  Thanks.  Do you know how to get background color opacity to render in IE.  I'm currently testing it with IE8 and no background is being rendered.  I'll paste the code in my original statement.

Comment: This might help: http://css-tricks.com/css-transparency-settings-for-all-broswers/ alternatively, you could use a semi-transparent background image.

Answer (score 0):

the position fixed option suggested earlier is probably the route I would go as well, but if you want an image in your overrlay that scrolls with the page, you could alter your getWindowSize() function to instead fetch the dimensions of a wrapper div that surrounds your content rather than the window dimentions.